# Selenium Waits Logic

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am building a testing framework for my website
I want to fully separate the framework away from test
the issue is when I write a test sometimes the Assert needs time until it can be true, for example if I am on Upload file page and when the file is uploaded the website should display File uploaded successfully page but it will need to much time until the browser reaches this page

How should I force the Assert to wait sometime before it returns result?

some code that might explain my current way of work:

Upload Page Class

```
Public class UploadPage
{
 [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "upload-button")]
 public IWebElement BtnUpload { get; set; }

  public UploadPage()
  {
   PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
  }

 public void UploadFile(string path)
  {
    //select file
    BtnUpload.Click();
  }
}
```

Successful Upload Page:

```
 Public class UploadSuccessfulPage
   {
     [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "success-message")]
     public IWebElement LblSuccessMessage{ get; set; }

     public UploadSuccessfulPage()
     {
       PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
     }
     public bool IsAt()
     {
      Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
      return Driver.url==configurations.UploadSuccessfulPageURL;
     }
   }
```

Test Method:

```
public void TestUpload()
{
 UploadPage uploadPage= new UploadPage ();
 uploadPage.UploadFile(path);
 UploadSuccessfulPage successPage= new UploadSuccessfulPage();
 Assert.IsTrue(successPage.IsAt());
}
```

when I write my tests this way the assert do not wait despite that IsAt() contains implicit wait

P.S: I am not intending to use Thread.Sleep();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `bool IsAt()` should be implemented like:

```
public bool IsAt()
{
  Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
  try {
     return driver.FindElement(By.Name("success-message").Displayed;
  } catch (WebDriverException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or using explicit wait:

```
public bool IsAt()
{
  try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
     wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("success-message")));
    return true;
  } catch (TimeoutException e){
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Update**:
If you want to verify by url, the `bool IsAt()` should look like:

```
public bool IsAt()
    {
      try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe(configurations.UploadSuccessfulPageURL));
        return true;
      } catch (TimeoutException e){
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Look at the class [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) to find a condition suitable to your require

Comment: thank you I will try it and get back to you, can you please shade some light on how this will solve the issue?

Comment: First, from your provided code for `bool IsAt()`, I don't see any logic there about what you expect it to do. Setting ImplicitWait will only affect any next command you call (like `driver.FindElement`).
The two examples I showed above say clearly about what method `IsAt()` should do - it is to check if the success message is displayed or not. I would prefer the second more though.

Comment: but I wrote in my IsAt method that under the implicitwait there is a condition that the label could be found

Comment: Could you show your code for `//LblSuccessMessage can be found on page`?

Comment: edited my question to show the actual idea I am using

Comment: since I am using page factory can I replace the find element calling with if(element!=null)

Comment: How do you navigate between pages in your framework? does every page has its own GoTo method or do other pages have methods like GoToOtherPage?

Comment: You can have both methods - it depends on what you want to do with them. In my case, I have a class PageBase with 2 methods: `void open()` to open that page, and `PageBase goto(string url)` to navigate to another page. For example, you are in the page `UploadSuccessfulPage`, you can navigate to the page `UploadPage`, by calling: `var nextPage = (UploadPage)UploadSuccessfulPage.GoTo(uploadPageUrl);`